# How to fill missing field values with linear interpolation?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, missing-data, linear-interpolation

I have a collection of documents representing values at specific dates.

Some of those dates don't have a value (the field can be missing or set to `null`).

I'd like to fill in those missing or undefined values by linearly interpolating with the closest previous and following documents ordered by date.

Such that:

```
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10 }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-08") }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15 }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: null }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-11") }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3 }
```

becomes:

```
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10   }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-08"), value: 12.5 } <=
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15   }
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: 11   } <=
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-11"), value: 7    } <=
{ date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting in `Mongo 5.3`, it's a nice use case for the new [`$fill`](https://docs.mongodb.com/upcoming/reference/operator/aggregation/fill/#fill-missing-field-values-with-linear-interpolation) aggregation operator:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: null }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3 }
db.aggregate(
  { $fill: {
      sortBy: { date: 1 },
      output: { value: { method: "linear" } }
  }}
)
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08"), value: 12.5 } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: 11   } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11"), value: 7    } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3    }
```

Documents are chronologically ordered by `date` (`sortBy: { date: 1 }`), such that missing `value`s are populated using a `linear` interpolation (`value: { method: "linear" }`) between previous and following values.

---

Note that this really is a linear interpolation based on the chosen `sortBy` field, such that if you had a missing date, you'd correctly get:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: null }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11") }
// => date gap <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-13"), value: 3 }
db.aggregate(
  { $fill: {
      sortBy: { date: 1 },
      output: { value: { method: "linear" } }
  }}
)
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08"), value: 12.5 } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: 12   } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11"), value: 9    } <=
// => date gap <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3    }
```

---

Also note that if you have gaps as mentioned just above and and also want to insert documents in place of those gaps, you can use a [`$densify`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v5.2/reference/operator/aggregation/densify/) stage to get the ultimate missing data filler!:

```
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08") }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15 }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: null }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11") }
// => date gap <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-13"), value: 3 }
db.aggregate(
  { $densify: {
      field: "date",
      range: { step: 1, unit: "day", bounds: "full" }
  }},
  { $fill: {
      sortBy: { date: 1 },
      output: { value: { method: "linear" } }
  }}
)
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-07"), value: 10   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-08"), value: 12.5 } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-09"), value: 15   }
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-10"), value: 12   } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-11"), value: 9    } <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 6    } <= <=
// { date: ISODate("2021-03-12"), value: 3    }
```